# PHP difference between saving .gif and .png files to disk

Tags: php

I'm keen to understand the difference between saving a .gif or .jpg (which seem to work fine using the code below), but does not work if I change it to .png

So this code works fine for .jpg or .gif images (links ending in .jpg or .gif)

```
$img = "http://www.anylocation.com/image.gif";
$ch = curl_init($img);
$fp = fopen($currentdir . 'image.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
echo "<b>Image stored...<br>";
```

But if I do this:

```
$img = "http://www.anylocation.com/image.png";
$ch = curl_init($img);
$fp = fopen($currentdir . 'image.png', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
echo "<b>Image stored...<br>";
```

It doesn't save the image, well, it tries to, but it just writes image.png with 0 byte size and no content.

Ideally I'd like to modify the above code so that it will work for any scenario or type of image. If not, and the code has to be different for .png, I could write in a 'check the extension of $img' and direct it to the correct piece of code.

Could anyone assist with the explanation of why this doesn't work with .png and if possible, any changes that I could make to make it work?

Comment: Does `http://www.anylocation.com/image.png` exist? If not, well then you know why...

Comment: could it be that your php-server just doesn't support `png`? You could test that with `if(function_exists('imagepng'))`

Comment: @Jeff cURL doesn't use any image manipulating functions. It just writes to the file.

Comment: I just tried your code with a gif and a png file and it worked fine for both. The url of the png image is: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-wmjRI5piPpo/UBwOCYjn-8I/AAAAAAAAELs/lHIL1oPaqsg/s1600/Estrella.png

Comment: Do you have a specific png url that you want me to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can reduce to ...

```
$img = "http://www.anylocation.com/image.png";
file_put_contents($currentdir . 'image.png', file_get_contents($img));
```

Comment: Can, but I don't recommend to use file functions for remote files. With cURL you can do different things on HTTP errors.